# Powershell vs variable file location

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am used to using `%~dp0` in automation scripts to ensure that my files can be located no matter where the deployment folder is placed.

`%~dp0` does not work so well in PowerShell an `$PSScriptRoot` & `$PSCommandPath` are not as user friendly

I can make this code uninstall and install an application without any issues.  The problem is I am having to declare the file location which does not always stay true.

GOOD, BUT MUST DECLARE LOCATION.

```
$RmvAppName = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "chrome"}
$RmvAppName.Uninstall() | Out-Null
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i c:\deploy\microsoft\edge.msi /passive ALLUSERS=1' | Out-Null
```

If I try to use a location variable that does not work for me. I have tried `Set-Location`, `Get-Location`, `$PSScriptRoot`, `$PSCommandPath` and nothing works.  I am simply looking for something in PowerShell that will give me the functionality of `%~dp0` and the power of PowerShell.

NO GOOD!

```
$RmvAppName = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "chrome"}
$location = Get-Location
$RmvAppName.Uninstall() | Out-Null
#Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i $(location)\edge.msi /passive ALLUSERS=1'
```

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhapse this will help?

```
PS> $RmvAppName = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "GO Contact Sync Mod"}

PS> $RmvAppName.Installsource
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\NAS-Downloads\Test\
```

Strangely enough I didn't get a response for "chrome" even though I have it installed.

You may want to read [this article](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/) about why not to use Win32_Product.

HTH

Comment: **Important**: the link  why not to query `Win32_Product`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [`Split-Path` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Split-Path) as follows:

```
Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
```

or

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand | Split-Path -Parent
```

**Explanation**:

Read *Links relative to the Batch Script* paragraph in [*How-to: Pass Command Line arguments (Parameters) to a Windows batch file.*](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

> `%~dp0` will return **the Drive and Path to the batch script**.

In a PowerShell script you can get the same info from the [`$myInvocation` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#myinvocation):

> **$MyInvocation**
>
> Contains information about the current command, such as the name,
> parameters, parameter values, and information about how the command
> was started, called, or invoked, such as the name of the script that
> called the current command.
>
> `$MyInvocation` is populated only for scripts, function, and script
> blocks. You can use the information in the
> System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo object that
> `$MyInvocation` returns in the current script, such as **the path and
> file name of the script** (`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`)  …